# Connecting to particular port inside a switch using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please find the below scenario:

1. I have one switch IP
2. For that switch multiple devices connected to multiple port numbers
3. Manually we will login to the switch with credentials
4. will give particular port number and click on enter two times
5. Then it will ask credentials of that particular device
6. After entering that credentials it will allow to login to that device.
7. Then we will give  some commands.

Please help me on  python code for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Try using pexpect module.

Install pexpect by `pip install pexpect`

Algorithm
1) Spawn a pexpect child by `child = pexpect.spawn('ssh user@switch-ip')`  or `pexpect.spawn('telnet switch-ip')`  or the protocol you use to login to the switch.
2) Then expect the prompt of the terminal(of the switch) like this `child.expect("#")`
3) Now you can run commands using `child.sendline("your command here")`

Do step 3 as many times as you would do manually. Now you can generalize the script by passing values as arguments. And everything will be done automatically.

**More about pexpect [here](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).**
**And here are few [examples](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html) in that same website.**

This should automate your scenario pretty easily.